# Refresh a div frequently without page refresh in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application that shows my system's CPU usages, total Memory, Uptime etc. details.

I want it to update the fields every 0.25 seconds using AJAX.
My index_controller.rb has this line:

```
class IndexController < ApplicationController
    def system_stats
    end
end
```

system_stats.html.erb:

```
<div class="centrify mb-4">
    <div class="logo">
        <svg class="pi-anim" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path fill="#00c1fd" d="M256 512A254 254 0 010 256 254 254 0 01256 0a254 254 0 01256 256 254 254 0 01-256 256z" data-original="#00C1FD"/><path fill="#08a8ee" d="M437 75C389 27 324 0 256 0v512a254 254 0 00256-256c0-68-27-133-75-181z" data-original="#08A8EE"/><g fill="#e4f7ff"><path class="info-i" d="M301 371V221H191v30h20v120h-21v30h130v-30zM256 191a45 45 0 100-90 45 45 0 000 90z" data-original="#E4F7FF"/></g><path class="info-i2" fill="#cbedfd" d="M256 191a45 45 0 000-90v90zM301 371V221h-45v180h64v-30z" class="active-path" data-old_color="#CBEDFD" data-original="#CBEDFD"/></svg>
    </div>

    <h1>System Stats</h1>
</div>

<% if Rails.env.production? %>
    <div class="centrify"><h6>Warning! On a Production Server this could mean nothing</h6></div>
    <hr>
<% end %>

<h4>Processor</h4>
<%= processor[0] %>
<%= "[ #{processor[1]} ]" %>
<hr>

<h4>CPU Usages</h4>
<%= %Q[#{cpu_usage.then { |x| "Total: #{x[0]}<br>[#{x.drop(1).join(', ')}]" }}].html_safe %>
<hr>

<h4>Memory</h4>
<%= "Total: #{memory} GiB" %>
<hr>

<h4>Uptime</h4>
<div id="uptime"><%= render 'stats/uptime', remote: true %></div>
<hr>
```

stats/_uptime.html.erb:

```rb
<%= "Uptime: #{uptime.map { |x| x.then { |y| y < 10 ? "0#{y}" : "#{y}" }}.join(?:)}" %>
```

index_helper.rb:

```
module IndexHelper
    def processor
        if File.readable?('/proc/cpuinfo')
            cpuinfo = IO.readlines('/proc/cpuinfo')
            model = cpuinfo.select { |x| x[/\Amodel\sname/] }
            [model[0].split(?:)[1].strip, model.count]
        else
            []
        end
    end

    def cpu_usage
        if File.readable?('/proc/stat')
            data = IO.readlines('/proc/stat').select! { |x| x[/^cpu\d*/] }.map! { |x| x.split.map!(&:to_f) }
            Kernel.sleep(0.075)
            prev_data = IO.readlines('/proc/stat').select! { |x| x[/^cpu\d*/] }.map! { |x| x.split.map!(&:to_f) }

            data.size.times.map do |x|
                %w(user nice sys idle iowait irq softirq steal).each_with_index { |el, ind| binding.eval("@#{el}, @prev_#{el} = #{data[x][ind + 1]}, #{prev_data[x][ind + 1]}") }

                previdle, idle = @prev_idle + @prev_iowait, @idle + @iowait
                totald = idle + (@user + @nice + @sys + @irq + @softirq + @steal) -
                    (previdle + (@prev_user + @prev_nice + @prev_sys + @prev_irq + @prev_softirq + @prev_steal))
                "#{((totald - (idle - previdle)) / totald * 100).round( x == 0 ? 2 : 0 ).then { |y| y.to_s == 'NaN' ? 0 : y }.abs}%"
            end
        else
            ''
        end
    end

    def memory
        if File.readable?('/proc/meminfo')
            meminfo = IO.readlines('/proc/meminfo')
            meminfo.find { |x| x[/^MemTotal/] }.split[1].to_i.fdiv(1024 ** 2).round(2)
        else
            0
        end
    end

    def uptime
        if File.readable?('/proc/uptime')
            uptime = IO.read('/proc/uptime').split[0].to_i
            [uptime / 3600, uptime % 3600 / 60, uptime % 60]
        else
            []
        end
    end
end
```

This works, but just for simplicity say I want to update the uptime div every 0.25 seconds, what's the way to do that? I have JQuery installed and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function to do an AJAX request every 0.25 seconds:

```js
function updateSystemInfo() {
  setInterval(function(){ 
    Rails.ajax({
      url: "/system_stats",
      type: "get",
      dataType: "script"
    });
 }, 0250);
}
```

Now your controller wants to respond to the JS request and will look for a `system_stats.js.erb` file. In that file you can tell rails to update the part of the view you want to update.

Now you can put the following part into a partial `_system_stats.html.erb`:

```html
<h4>Processor</h4>
<%= processor[0] %>
<%= "[ #{processor[1]} ]" %>
<hr>

<h4>CPU Usages</h4>
<%= %Q[#{cpu_usage.then { |x| "Total: #{x[0]}<br>[#{x.drop(1).join(', ')}]" }}].html_safe %>
<hr>

<h4>Memory</h4>
<%= "Total: #{memory} GiB" %>
<hr>
```

And on the `system_stats.html.erb` you place an empty div with an ID, for example `<div id="system_stats"></div>`

Now in the `system_stats.js.erb` you tell rails to render the partial in the div with ID system_stats.

```rb
$("#system_stats").html("#{escape_javascript(render 'system_stats')}");
```

Now every 0.25 seconds the partial will be rerenderd.

Comment: I have the exact same route "system_stats" which takes to the "index#system_stats", and I put the `import Rails from '@rails/ujs'` and then `setInterval(funciton() { Rails.ajax...` code. For some reason, if I do `console.log('something')` to the system_stats.js.erb located in app/views/index/, it doesn't work, and nothing is getting printed.

Comment: If you put the console.log('something') in your `application.js` do you see it than?

Comment: Yes, I have wrapped that in `$(() => { ... })` of jquery, console.log() works as expected. The setInterval you wrote actually sends AJAX request (can be seen by enabling XHR in Firefox),  but it actually doesn't render the system_stats.js.erb.

Comment: What are the logs in the terminal showing? Something like `GET "/system_stats" ....` `Processing by IndexController#system_stats as ` What is the as saying? `JS` `HTML` `*` ?

Comment: The XHR message is `XHR GET http://localhost:8080/system_stats
[HTTP/1.1 200 OK 188ms]` and it's printed with a delay of whatever time I have in the setInterval

Comment: yeah but what is the terminal log saying? How does it wants to process it?

Comment: The code in system_stats.js has console.log() for the test, which prints nothing, that means it's not rendered. The rails app shows nothing related to the js.erb file. It just renders out the html.erb file.

Comment: So your JS is not working for some reason. How does your `application.js` looks?

Comment: Hi, here's the application.js: https://github.com/Souravgoswami/rails_pi/blob/master/app/javascript/packs/application.js

Changes: I have appended rails ajax  in JQuery's document.ready `$( () => { ... } )`.

Comment: So if you paste the JS part from my example on line 64, and add a console.log to it can you see it?

Comment: Yes it works. The thing that doesn't  work as expected is the system_stats.js.erb, it's ignored and not rendered for some reason.

Comment: That's why I asked several times what's in your terminal logs, how is it being processed.

Comment: If you meant standard output  generated by the server, it's `Started GET "/system_stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-08-14 15:24:23 +0530
Processing by IndexController#system_stats as */*
  Rendering index/system_stats.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered stats/_uptime.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 27)
  Rendered index/system_stats.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 96.2ms | Allocations: 1183)
Completed 200 OK in 132ms (Views: 129.8ms | Allocations: 11336)`

Same output printed every second after adding Rails.ajax line in setInterval() with 1000 ms delay.

Comment: So it is not being processed as JS, can you add `dataType: 'script'` to the request options.

Comment: Wow! Thanks it was a pretty annoying journey... Adding `dataType: 'script'` fixes the problem... Thanks a lot for the guide! Now I can sort out refreshing the page with jQuery... Meanwhile, can you update the answer so that I can mark it accepted solution?

Comment: Just to let you know, a problem with the approach is that system_stat page is requested even when I am on other pages. The standard output from server is every 0.5s is: `Started GET "/system_stats" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-08-14 21:30:04 +0530
Processing by IndexController#system_stats as JS
  Rendering index/system_stats.js.erb
  Rendered stats/_cpu_usage.html.erb (Duration: 78.4ms | Allocations: 752)
  Rendered stats/_memory.html.erb (Duration: 0.6ms | Allocations: 43)
  ...
  ...
  ...
Completed 200 OK in 86ms (Views: 84.5ms | Allocations: 2235)` On any page...

Comment: Haha yes it does. Before sending the request you can check if the page has an element with id system_stats. If not than dont do the request

Comment: Yes, that's the thing I did, I moved the whole code in `document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => { ... })` and checking if an element with an id is present or not, if it does,t it runs the `setInterval()` function, otherwise it clears the interval...